# What type of adverb is this?

Tags: adverbs

This is a question from my book:

> Always speak the truth.
>
> (a). Simple adverb of Number
>
> (b). Simple adverb of Manner
>
> (c). Simple adverb of Negation
>
> (d). Simple adverb of Degree

Book says that the answer is (b).

I don't agree with the answer key. As far as I know Always is the adverb of frequency.

So none of the option is correct in my opinion.

Am I missing something here? 
[image]

Comment: The book is wrong, I'm afraid. In your example, "always" is a frequency adverb. A manner adverb would be, for example "Speak the truth decisively".

Answer (score 2):

While "always" *is* a degree of frequency, that is not an option in your multiple choice question. If you consider the *context* the answer does make sense.

Consider:

- I always speak the truth
- Smoke is always coming out of that chimney

Do you think that the same *frequency* is implied by both these statements? A chimney could bellow smoke 24 hours a day, but does the first statement mean that truth is constantly coming out of your mouth every second of every minute? Obviously not.

Therefore "I always speak the truth" is not *really* a statement about *how often* you speak - it is saying that when you do speak, you are truthful. It is saying something about your *manner*, which is defined as "a person's outward bearing or way of *behaving* towards others".

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes a lot of sense. It is clear to me now. Have a good day!!